# Update my plot each time parameters change

Tags: matlab

using GUIDE I have now a programm whose output is a vector and a plot of its data. Because the plot has many little variations, I used the csaps function to get a smoothier plot. I want now to add a slider to my figure to change the smoothing parameter and I want that the plot to be updated each time the value of the slider changes. How can I do this? I found this on mathworks.com but I coudn't apply it to my case: https://de.mathworks.com/help/control/ref/stepplot.html .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add callback to your slider. To do so in GUIDE press right mouse button on the slider and select view callbacks -> callback. It will create something like this in .m file of your GUIDE object:

```
function slider_Callback(hObject, eventdata, handles)
% hObject    handle to slider (see GCBO)
% eventdata  reserved - to be defined in a future version of MATLAB
% handles    structure with handles and user data (see GUIDATA)

% Hint: get(hObject,'Value') returns toggle state of slider
```

Everything you will place under `%Hint` would be executed every time the slider is changing its state. For example you can re-plot the graph:

```
% Hint: get(hObject,'Value') returns toggle state of slider
plot(x_value,y_value);
```

Comment: Hi @Karls, 

thanks for your answer. I didn't want this alternative. The slider should be under my plot. I found the solution with this code: 

`fig1 = figure 
surf(x,y,smoother.'); 
slider = uicontrol('Style','slider','Min',slmin,'Max',slmax,... 'Position',[20 20 200 20]); 
set(slider,'Callback',@(hObject,eventdata) surf(csaps(z,result,get(hObject,'Value'),z) )) ; `

It works as I wanted. Now I want my new surface without shading. Where should I put **shading interp**; in the slider callback?

Comment: Callback is needed in the place, where you want some event to trigger the change. If you need shading off permanently, you can put it in your main script. If the slider change should trigger it - put it in the same place as `plot(x_value,y_value)` in above example code.